# Postgres: Make updates without doing INSERT/DELETE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing an application where it is necessary to update tables with large number of rows (greater than 10 million) quite frequently. I use Postgres.

After reading this article (http://blog.codacy.com/2015/05/14/how-to-update-large-tables-in-postgresql/) I realised that each update in Postgres is actually an equivalent of an `INSERT` and a `DELETE`.

This frustrates me greatly because large table `UPDATE` operations are really slow.

Is it possible to turn this behaviour off? Is it possible to make postgres `UPDATE` in place instead of `INSERT` and `DELETE` operations?

Comment: If it's possible, then Postgres will do in-place updates automatically. This is called "HOT" - Heap Only Tuples: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD  The fact that an UPDATE writes a new row is built deeply into the MVCC implementation of Postgres and can't be changed.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41059/optimizing-bulk-update-performance-in-postgresql